# Center cell borders when using \multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{4} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{5} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{6} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{7} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{8}\\
        \hline
        \(f(x)\)&a&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{b}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{c}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{d}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{e}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{f}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{g}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{h}&i\\
        \hline
        a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&j&i&k&l&m&n&o&p&q\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that the cell borders are perfectly centered:

[image: Screenshot of the MWE above]

Unfortunately, inserting (longer) formulas will destroy the layout:

```
% excerpt
&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\(-\frac{5}{4}\pi - \frac{1}{2}\)} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\(-\frac{5}{4}\pi - \frac{1}{2}\)} &
```

[image: Screenshot of the MWE above with longer formulas added]

Questions:

1.) Is there any better way to achieve my tabular layout?

2.) If not, how can I resolve the layout problem?

(3.) Removing the last row (a – q) also causes an incorrect layout. If this behavior can be corrected in any (easy) way (maybe as a side effect of choosing another way), I'd be glad to hear about it. Otherwise, I will probably ask another question.)

---

I've drawn a quick sketch in Word, maybe it helps to understand my problem:
[image: Sketch]

It's not perfect, but you should get the very idea.

Comment: Is this 'destroyed' layout not the result of the second row, where you use as 2nd column 'a', then a two - column wide 'b' etc, and finally a column with 'i'? Is there any particular need for this layout?

Comment: @ChristianH. Those widths are by design. I want the cells' borders in the second row to exactly match the middles of the cells above them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `tabularx` package and its eponymous environment, along with a centered version of the `X` column type that's provided by the `tabularx` package, to guarantee that the basic 17 columns are all equally wide, regardless of the actual contents.

In the code below, note that I've replaced most `{|c|}` alignment directives with `{c|}` to avoid getting double-struck vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{.5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{17}{C|}} % 17 columns, all equally wide by design
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$-\frac{5}{4}\pi - \frac{1}{2}$} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$-\frac{5}{4}\pi - \frac{1}{2}$} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{4} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{6} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{8}\\
\hline
$f(x)$
&a
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{c}
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{d} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{e}
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{f} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{g}
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{h} &i \\
\hline
a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&j&i&k&l&m&n&o&p&q\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! However, is there a way to remove the last row (a..q) without causing an incorrect reflow of the table? I noticed that `\onslide` from Beamer can perfectly hide that row (leaving an empty space of course - it doesn't matter). So using the internal mechanism of `\onslide` would be a viable option. I'am already digging in the Beamer's source code - more or less :)

Comment: @ComFreek - I guess you could define a "null" cell command such as `\newcommand\nn{\multicolumn{1}{C}{}}` (note the uppercase `C`) and then replace each of the `a`, `b`, etc in the final row with `\nn`. Oh, that, and leave off the final `\hline`...